# Error populating XML with PHP from SQLServer

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a database in SQL Server, and I want to populate the XML document from my database, using PHP. But when I open the populate.php file I have the error below...

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\populate.php on line 6
```

My php file is like below:

```
<?php

$server = "USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$options = array("UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"", "Database"=>"RESTORANTET");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

$sql = "SELECT Emri_Pjates, Cmimi, Pershkrimi FROM dbo.MENU FOR XML PATH";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
$xml = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);

?>
```

Please can you help me? Why sqlsrv_connect() is unidentified?  I am not sure about the username and password.. When I enter the SQL Server ,I enter with Windows Authentification, and I dont use any username or password...That is why I have leave UID amd PWD empty here..Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your php does not have the neccessary driver to connect to sql server.
download sql server driver for php [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Comment: Thanks I will try it, and come back to you

Comment: is it necessary to have  SQL server extension? Because I dont see it in my computer. Where can I find it, in order to install it? Or it is enough to install only the link you gave to me?

Comment: Which version to install SQLSRV30.EXE or SQLSR20.EXE? I have the SQL Server 2008...Thanks for all your help

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: i can't, i don't know how to install that. i just pointed out the problem and how to solve it. if you need details you might as well google about it.